# Return first word of the string

Tags: python, string

I has a data like below:

```
Colindale London                                        
London Borough of Bromley                               
Crystal Palace, London                                  
Bermondsey, London                                      
Camden, London
```

This is my code:

```
def clean_whitespace(s):
    out = str(s).replace(' ', '')
    return out.lower()
```

My code now just return the string that has been remove white space. How can I select the first word the the string. For example:

```
Crystal Palace, London -> crystal-palace                             
Bermondsey, London -> bermondsey                                      
Camden, London -> camden
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
s = 'Bermondsey, London'

def clean_whitespace(s):
    out = str(s).split(',', 1)[0]
    out = out.strip()
    out = out.replace(' ', '-')
    return out.lower()

print(clean_whitespace(s))
```

Output:

```
bermondsey
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
s =  "Crystal Palace, London"
output = s.split(',')[0].replace(' ', '-').lower()
print(output)
```